# Using Box OAuth with AngularJS route system

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, box-api

I'm trying to authenticate users into an AgularJS app that uses routes based on hash (#) URLs.

So I'm calling

GET https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize

with redirect_uri contaning an URL with a hash-based route, for example http://myapp.mydomain.com/#box.

Then after granting access, I am redirected to something like: http://myapp.mydomain.com/?code=CODE#/box .

The problem is that the hash part is after the query params, so it is not matching my route rule:

```
    state('box', {
      url: "/box?code",
      template: "<p>BOX</p>"
    })
```

How can I make this URL match my route?

Comment: Look at this https://oauth.io/

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work by listening to [$locationChangeStart event](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#events_%24locationchangestart) and then I "fix" the URL by putting the hash route before the query params.

This way, it matches my route with the `code` parameter correctly filled.